# Spring ignores my ContentNegotiatingViewResolver

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am building a simple REST service which should return the data encoded as either JSON or [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) (depending on what the client requests). I have followed [the tutorial on vivin.net](http://vivin.net/2011/07/01/implementing-jsonp-in-spring-mvc-3-0-x/).

**WEB-INF/config/config.xml**:

```
<beans ...>
  ...
  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="favorPathExtension" value="true"/>
    <property name="mediaTypes">
      <map>
        <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
        <entry key="jsonp" value="application/javascript" />
      </map>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultViews">
      <list>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView" />
        <bean class="cz.dusanrychnovsky.utils.json.MappingJacksonJsonpView" />
      </list>
    </property>
  </bean>
</beans>
```

**MappingJacksonJsonpView.java**

```
public class MappingJacksonJsonpView extends MappingJacksonJsonView
{
    public static final String DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE = "application/javascript";

    @Override
    public String getContentType() {
        return DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE;
    }

    @Override
    public void render(Map<String, ?> model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws Exception 
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

When I try to request `http://localhost:8080/service/resource.jsonp`, though, Spring would still use the MappingJacksonJsonView (as the log reveals) and returns the output encoded as JSON (instead of JSONP).

What am I doing wrong?

In case I have omitted some important details, please ask for them. I will update the post right away.

Comment: Essentially this looks to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085088/jackson-annotations-being-ignored-in-spring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be better off following the tutorial provided at spring.io:

http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

If you're using a recent version of Spring, it automatically does Jackson marshalling. So you shouldn't have any of the code above.

Comment: The problem is that I need the response to be marshaled into [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), not JSON, to be able to bypass [the same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: In that case, use the answer provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15282617/implementing-jsonp-in-spring-mvc-3-2

Comment: Thank you. Despite the fact that this solution (IMO) breaks the MVC abstraction rules (presentation issues are dealt with inside the controller) it seems to be the best currently available one for Spring based REST services.

Comment: It's a bit puzzling actually. Spring-data-rest does provide built in JSONP config (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/wiki/JSONP-Support-in-Spring-Data-REST), but Spring MVC doesn't seem to support it out of the box yet. Maybe soon?